# Backbone.js: Why isn't event firing the second time (delegateEvents did not help)

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

This seems to be a popular topic, however, after trying several proposed solutions from 5 different answers I still can't get it right. I have a simple form that appends input from two fields to the screen. "Add" button works once (the entered data is displayed) and does not fire its event on the second click (I checked - the event's `render` is not executed any more). Most of suggested fixes involve adding `this.delegateEvents()` at the end of the views' `render` methods -  did not have any effect in my case, maybe I did not do it right. I think what I am doing is just simpler that those issues other guys had to tackle.

I realize that the whole thing can be structured better/differently, I just followed one of the tutorials and got stuck at that second click issue.  I just want to know: 1. exactly what in my code caused that bug. 2. how to overcome it, preferably without rewriting the whole thing.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Name List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="name_book.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container"></div>     
    <div class="div_people"></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="div_inputs"></div>
</div>


<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

<!--template for the inputs-->
<script type="text/template" id="inputs">
    Please enter name and city below:<br>
    <form id="add_person_form" class="add_person_form">
    <div id="div_input_name" class="input_name" style="float:left"><input id="input_name" type="text" /></div>
    <div class="div_input_city" style="float:left"><input id="input_city" type="text" /></div>
    <a href="#/add" class="input_submit_submit">Add</a>
    </form>
</script>

<!--template for the screen output row-->
<script type="text/template" id="person_info">
    <span class="person_name"><%= person_name %></span>
    <span class=spacer></span>
    <span class="person_city"><%= person_city %></span>
    <br>
</script>

<script>
    //class constructor
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'home',
            'add': 'addPerson'
        }
    });

    var router = new Router();

    var InputsList = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.div_inputs',
        render: function() {
            var template = _.template($('#inputs').html(), {});
            this.$el.append(template);
        }
    });

    var inputsList = new InputsList();
    router.on('route:home', function() {
        inputsList.render();
    });         

    var PeopleList = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.div_people',
        render: function() {        
            var template_person = _.template( $("#person_info").html(), {person_name: $("#input_name").val(), person_city: $("#input_name").val()} );
            this.$el.append(template_person);
        }
    });

    var peopleList = new PeopleList();

    router.on('route:addPerson', function() {
        peopleList.render();
    });     

    Backbone.history.start();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because you're already on that route after the first click? Maybe you should make it an onclick event instead of a route?

Answer (score 1):

if the route `#/add` does not change, then there is nothing that would trigger a change.
if you want a notification on every click, you need to listen to a click event.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    events : {
        "click .input_submit_submit" : "myCallbackOnClick"
    },
    myCallbackOnClick : function(ev) {
        // <a> i was clicked
        ev.preventDefault();
        this.someOptionToRenderDifferently = true;
        peopleList.render();
    }
});
```

Comment: So my problem is confusing 'routes' and 'events that execute code'. I will try your suggestion. Does it mean I need to split the submit button into a separate view? I do not want any events to be executed when user clicks the text inputs.

Comment: well, route changes are events, too. but they fire only once. if the route is already "#/add" nothing changes...

Comment: actually you dont need to change any view logic. as i see it correclty, you just want to say `peopleList.render()`. Check my updated answer. I hope it fixes your problem!

Comment: My input_submit_submit contains both submit button and the text inputs. I don't want any event when I click on text inputs, only on the button. So I decoupled those two into two views and the rest is what you suggested. Thanks! I still don't have 15 required points to vote your answer up, sorry..